# Solve $x^x=2x$ where $x\in\mathbb C$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $x^x=2x$ where $x\in\mathbb C$.

Obviously, one solution is $x=2$. By WA, another solution is $x=0.346...$. How to solve it analytically, e.g. using Lambert W function?

Thank you.

Comment: What is WA please ?

Comment: WA is Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I can show you how I started:

The Lambert W function is given as $z=W(z)*e^{W(z)}$. What you are trying to obtain is a expression on x which matches this function.

You can start with $x^x=2x$
using the logarithm you obtain $x\ln{x}=\ln{2x}=\ln{2}+\ln{x}$.
Then: $$x\ln{x}-\ln{x}=\ln{2}$$
$$(x-1)\ln{x}=\ln{2}$$
$$e^{\ln{x-1}}\ln{x}=\ln{2}$$
Now we almost arrived at the desired form. However,  $x-1$ is still causing troubles...

Comment: What about http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+log%28abs%28%282%2Bx%2Bi*y%29^%282%2Bx%2Bi*y%29-2*%282%2Bx%2Bi*y%29%29%29+for+x%3D-4+to+4

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: your link broke, could you write out the function another way so we can read it?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how I can do that. It is just calling WA with the command "plot log(abs((2+x+y*i)^(2+x+y*i)-2*(2+x+y*i))) for x=-4 to +4"

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: that's what I was hoping for, thank you

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: so what function is being plotted there and how does it relate to this question?

Comment: @abiessu:??? it's just plotting the absolute value of the function $ g(x)= (2+x)^(2+x)-2(2+x) = 0$ over the complex numbers. Because we know apriori, that one solution of the original function $f(z)$ is at $z_0=2$ I shift the function to let the center of the coordinate-system at $z=2$. After that, the solutions are, where the *absolute value* equals zero (the real coordinate must then be recentered). After that, the *log* enhances the display of the zeros to make them better visible in the plot.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms: thank you, I was missing the "recenter due to known solution" piece.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10985/discussion-between-abiessu-and-gottfried-helms)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x^x=2x$$

$$=e^{x\ln x}=e^{(a+bi)(\ln|a+bi|+i(\arg(a+bi)+2k\pi))}$$

$$=e^{a\ln|a+bi|-b(\arg(a+bi)+2k\pi)}\cdot e^{bi\ln|a+bi|+ai(\arg(a+bi)+2k\pi)}$$

$$\implies {e^{a\ln|a+bi|}\over e^{b(\arg(a+bi)+2k\pi)}}=2|a+bi|$$

$$\text{and}\qquad e^{bi\ln|a+bi|+ai(\arg(a+bi)+2k\pi)}={a+bi\over|a+bi|}$$

$$\implies (a^2+b^2)^{a-1\over 2}=2e^{b\arg(a+bi)+2bk\pi}\tag 1$$

$$\text{and}\qquad\text{cis}(b\ln\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a\arg(a+bi)+2ak\pi)=\text{cis}(\arg(a+bi)+2l\pi)\tag 2$$

$$(2)\implies \frac b2\ln(a^2+b^2)+(a-1)\arg(a+bi)=2l\pi-2ak\pi\tag 3$$

This is almost to the point of evaluating all-real numbers.  Fortunately, many graphing programs will evaluate $\arctan(\tfrac ba)$ using all branches and correctly evaluating at e.g. $x=0$ such that $\arg(a+bi)$ can be graphed as $\arctan(\tfrac ba)$.  Here are some graphs with $a$ along the $x$-axis and $b$ along the $y$-axis:

[image: Wide angle view of magnitude (red) vs. angle (green) functions]

[image: Closeup of real solutions and first complex solution]

As demonstrated in the pictures, there are the three real solutions at $x\approx -0.658, 0.346, 2$, and there are many complex solutions, one of which is near the location $3+3i$.

Also, we have two equations to work with, so we can continue the direct analysis:

$$(1)\implies a^2+b^2=(2e^{b\arg(a+bi)+2bk\pi})^{2\over a-1}$$

Plugging into $(2)$:

$$\frac b2\ln((2e^{b\arg(a+bi)+2bk\pi})^{2\over a-1})+(a-1)\arg(a+bi)=2l\pi-2ak\pi$$

$$=\frac b{a-1}(b\arg(a+bi)+2bk\pi)\ln2+(a-1)\arg(a+bi)$$

$$=\frac {b^2\ln 2+(a-1)^2}{a-1}\arg(a+bi)+\frac{2b^2k\pi\ln 2}{a-1}$$

Unfortunately, this doesn't lend itself to any further breakdown that I am aware of.  The graph is not easy to create, since the branches appear to be a near-full covering of 2D space, and even setting e.g. $k=1$ only makes for confusing graphs that do not correspond to the solutions identified above.